# Edit tab not in Tools panel

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I do not have the Edit tab in the Tools panel.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because this is not a question.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you uploaded a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 2.79: it only exists in Object mode.

Select this mode from the header/footer of the Viewport (or, if you are in Edit mode, just hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>)

---

If you are using Blender 2.80+ and following a <2.79 tutorial, then most of the transforms that used to be under *Tools > Edit* are now in the header of the Viewport under "Object".